# How to detect arrow key-presses in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, keyboard-events, arrow-keys

I am making a car racing game in JavaScript. The car is controlled by the arrow keys. I have made a lot of games in JavaScript before and it worked.
The code I had used is:

```
function detectKey(e) {
    var event = window.event ? window.event : e;
    if (true) {
        alert(event.keyCode)
    }
}
```

Now I am using this code the first time for arrow keys. Whenever I press the arrow keys the the page is moving up and down. I am not understanding the problem. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3):

Heres a list of all the keycodes http://mikemurko.com/general/jquery-keycode-cheatsheet/ 
 - Enter: 13
 - Up: 38
 - Down: 40
 - Right: 39
 - Left: 37

```
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 38) {
          //up was pressed
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use keyCode like below :

```
$(document).on('keypress','your-element',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 40)
    console.log("Arrow key pressed");
})
```

Answer (score -3):

in pure JavaScript

```
document.onkeydown = function myFunction() {
switch (event.keyCode) {
case 38:
    console.log("Up key is pressed");
    break;
case 40:
    console.log("Down key is pressed");
    break;
case 37:
    console.log("Right key is pressed");
    break;
case 39:
    console.log("left key is pressed");
    break;
}
```

}

Comment: The keys codes you provided are not correct

Comment: Up: 38
Down: 40
Right: 39
Left: 37

Comment: onkeypress can't detect arrow keys! use keydown instead.